# Laravel Eloquent Builder removes the leading zero from the string that binds

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-6

I need to find all results that include this substring (note the leading zero):

```
$code = '02549';

Nomenclature::where('code', 'like', '%' . $code . '%')->get();
```

With such a builder, I get the correct request:

```
select * from `nomenclatures` where `code` like '%02549%'
```

but if I use a condition in the builder:

```
Nomenclature::when(true, function($query, $code) {
    $query->where('code', 'like', '%' . $code . '%');
})->get();
```

then I receive such a request (there is no leading zero):

```
select * from `nomenclatures` where `code` like '%1%'
```

Can someone explain what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think your code should be like this:

```
Nomenclature::when(true, function($query) use ($code) {
    $query->where('code', 'like', '%' . $code . '%');
})->get();
```

Comment: yes, I was wrong. The value from the condition is passed to the callback.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want put $code in the closure as an argument, use this way:

```
Nomenclature::when($code, function($query, $code) {
    $query->where('code', 'like', '%' . $code . '%');
})->get();
```